# File name is inserted into database but file is not reached to the destination folder

Tags: php

This is my code for file upload , with this code file name reached to the database but file is not reached to the destination folder.

```
if(isset($_FILES['imageFile']['name'])){
         $imageFile=$_FILES['imageFile']['name'];
       }else{
        $imageFile='';  
       }
        $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
       if($imageFile!=''){
           $fileArray =explode(".",$imageFile);
           $extension = end($fileArray);
           if(in_array($extension,$allowedExts)){
               $newFileName=round(microtime(true)).'.'.$extension;
               $uploadPath = "assets/images/".$newFileName;
               $uploadDone = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imageFile']['tmp_name'],$uploadPath);
           }
           else{
               $message='This type file is not allowed';
           }

       }
```

and this is my html code through which am trying to get file.

```
<p>Upload Your Profile Picture: <input type="file" size=65 name="imageFile" id="imageFile"></p><br>
```

Comment: What errors do you get? Have you made sure your script has the right permissions to write to your folder?

Comment: yes  folder have right permissions and when am trying to show the uploaded image on the listing page it shows an error 404 file is not found becuase in actually file is not uploaded but it reached into the database.

Answer (score 0):

Add absolute path `dirname(__FILE__)` for `$uploadPath`

```
$folder = dirname(__FILE__);
$uploadPath = $folder."/assets/images/".$newFileName;
```

`dirname(__FILE__);` will give you current folder name set it where you want

Use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` to get unform separator

```
DEFINE('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

and use like this

```
$uploadPath = $folder.DS.'assets'.DS.'images'.DS.$newFileName;
```

Comment: done but still not working.....it reached into the databse but not move to the destination folder.

Comment: share `$uploadPath` ?

Comment: it is something like this..                                     $folder = dirname(__FILE__);                $uploadPath = $folder."/assets/images/".$newFileName;
 $uploadDone = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imageFile']['tmp_name'],$uploadPath);

Comment: share actual value of `echo $uploadPath;` ?

Comment: C:\wamp64\www\registration/assets/images/1532417483.jpg

Comment: do you actually have this path `C:\wamp64\www\registration\assets\images` ?

Comment: C:\wamp64\www\registration\assets\images\..........i have this path but still not working

Answer (score 0):

> Use complete destination folder path (i.e. absolute path) to place uploaded file. Use "ROOT URL" variable.
>
> As if you are using windows system then path should be like this 
>   `C:/wamp or xamp/www/projectName/folderName/`
>
> In case of linux system path should be like /var/www/html/projectName
>
> Example 
>   `$uploadPath = WWW_ROOT."/assets/images/".$newFileName;`

Comment: still not working,am getting this error  "The requested URL /registration/assets/images/20180212_164112.jpg was not found on this server."

Comment: you are using windows or linux ?

Comment: am using windows

Comment: replace forward slash with backward slash in path replace C:\wamp64\www\registration\assets\images 
with
C:/wamp64/www/registration/assets/images
Try to print URL before generating file and see the difference.

Comment: i use DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR so it take in the right way and when i use echo to print path i get C:\wamp64\www\registration\assets\images\.....which is right but still file is not move to the folder.

Answer (score 0):

My code is working fine ,issue was actually i was trying to upload image of size 3 MB but in directory the size is defined as 2 MB so when i was trying to upload an image less than 2 MB it uploaded successfully. so whenever this type of error occur trying to upload size less than defined size or increase size from directory.